# Datediff last and previous dates SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm learning SQL, for an exercise I have to several things.

I'm making a query to compare the most recent orderdate with the orderdate before. I want to use a correlated subquery for this. I have already made it using a Cross Apply and Window functions.

At the moment I have this:

```
select 
    b1.klantnr, 
    DATEDIFF(D, (Select MAX(b1.Besteldatum)), 
                (Select MAX(b1.Besteldatum) 
                 where besteldatum not in (Select MAX(b1.besteldatum)))) as verschil 
from 
    bestelling b1 
group by 
    b1.klantnr, b1.besteldatum
```

I only get `null` values in the datediff column. It should return this:

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPvBB.png)

I'm using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: why are you fixated on doing this with a correlated subquery? there are other ways of doing this. also, which version of sql server are you using? add these details to the question please.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A correlated subquery way.

```
select top 1 bs.*,datediff(day,
                           (select max(bs1.Besteldatum) 
                            from bestelling bs1 
                            where bs1.Besteldatum<bs.Besteldatum),
                           bs.Besteldatum
                          ) as diff
from bestelling bs
order by bs.Besteldatum desc
```

This gives only the difference between latest date and the date preceding it. If you need all records remove `top 1` from the query.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one simple way:

```
select datediff(day, min(bs.Besteldatum), max(bs.Besteldatum)) as most_recent_diff
from (select top (2) bs.*
      from bestelling bs
      order by bs.Besteldatum
     ) bs;
```

This uses a subquery, but not a correlated subquery.  Should have really good performance, if you have an index on `bestselling(Besteldatum)`.